# Can {a,b,c}*a^n{a,b,c}*b^n{a,b,c}*c^n{a,b,c} be accepted by an FSA?

Tags: finite-automata, state-machine

I'm looking at some exercices that reguards FSAs and my teacher is giving and odd solution for the language

[image]

I would have solved that language with a Not-Deterministic TM cause you have to remember n for a, b and c.

This is the given solution
[image]
Is this solution incorrect?

Comment: Please explain how the `n` in the expression is to be understood. Is a word in the language if there is an `n` such that the words is contained in the expression? Is the accepted language the union over all possible integers of the expression? Must the repetition of the characters powered by `n` be the same?

Comment: Between every casual string composed by a,b,c there must be a^n, b^n and c^n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example above does work and therefore is correct.
It is clear that for `n = 1` the FSA posted above does work.
Now let's condiser the case n > 1, we have to have the same amount of a, b and c between every possible string composed of {a,b,c}. This string can be seen as the same string with n = 1 and the other n - 1 repetitions can be put in the {a,b,c}* group of strings, hence this FSA can accept that language correctly.

Comment: Unless the problem stipulates that n must be positive, this solution is incorrect as it does not accept the empty string. You might want to update the question or answer to address this and, possibly, review the materials provided by your teacher and bring this issue to his or her attention. It is possible that n > 0 is implied but that is not the usual convention.